# How can I do background work in python 3 Google App Engine standard environment?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have an endpoint on my appengine app (`/start`) that I use to kick off a process. In the python 2 environment I used `deferred` to run the process outside of the request context. On appengine flex, you can [run background threads](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#background_threads) that live outside of the request environment. At first look, I thought this was [also true](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#background_threads) of the python 3 standard environment, however at a closer look it contains this note:

> However note that new threads or processes may not run after the inbound request is served.

Does this mean that once the request is served the background thread that I started will be killed? If so, what is the best way to start background work?

I could re-create the `deferred` library by creating a queue in cloud task and pickling everything, but that's a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#task_queue) section of the [Understanding differences between Python 2 and Python 3 on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences) guide:

> You can use [Cloud Tasks (beta)](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs) to access the Task Queue service.
>
> In cases where pull queues are appropriate, such as queuing up tasks
>   or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate workers,
>   [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs) can be a good alternative. Cloud Pub/Sub offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

So yes, cloud tasks is the recommended solution.

But you don't really need to re-create the `deferred` library - that one was built on top of the push task queues. The only advantage of the `deferred` library over the push tasks was that you didn't have to pre-register handlers for the tasks (you'd just pass the function to be executed and its args). But that's not true for the cloud tasks - they do require [GAE handlers](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers).

Comment: Thanks for the response! So yes I understand that Cloud Tasks is the successor to Task Queues. However, I was hoping that I could avoid using that altogether and just spawn a background thread similar to appengine flex. Is this not possible?

Comment: Not really, according to the doc you quoted.

Comment: https://github.com/freshplanet/AppEngine-Deferred should be portable to GAE Py3